# Theme/Plugin installation through url on button click

Tags: plugins, themes, installation

I have a specific page on my website with several plugins and themes for download. Free plugins and themes. I offer a link to download them but I am trying to give my users this content in a more elegant way. What I would like to do is having urls that when clicked, the plugin installs on their website and is being pulled from my web hosting server. Is this achievable? I saw something similar in the main WPMUDEV plugin, however they use a plugin. I would also like to know how to do the same thing but through a custom plugin of my own like WPMUDEV did.

Comment: This is a very broad question and the solution would be quite involved. This sounds like a very dangerous thing to try to implement as well.

Comment: Why do you think this is very dangerous mate?

Comment: It sounds like you want users to click a link on one site and have files installed on another. That is opening a very, very big door.

Comment: This would happen only if they are logged in on their wordpress admin dashboard. Ex. you click the button, the tab displaying you wp-admin opens and if logged in it starts the installation process.

Comment: That still looks like a big door, even if you could get it to work. I would never trust that system, personally. Even if the system itself is secure you are shoving code onto my site that I haven't seen and that hasn't been at least minimally vetted (as the code on the theme and plugin repos has been).

Comment: I would like to just do it like the default wordpress repository works when you click "add new" plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33604/discussion-between-arg-geo-and-s-ha-dum).